# I want to remove the bottomTab whenever I get redirected to the login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to remove the bottom tab whenever I get redirected to the login page, I already got set the bar on all pages, but when I click to login, the bar is always there.

This is my code right now:

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import Login from "../screens/login.js";
import Home from "../screens/home.js";
import Event from "../screens/event.js";
import Local from "../screens/local.js";
import Profile from "../screens/profile.js";
import ticket from "../screens/ticket.js";
import { Context } from "../globalContext/globalContext.js";
import { Foundation, FontAwesome5, FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const StackNavigator = () => {
  const globalContext = useContext(Context);
  const { isLoggedIn } = globalContext;

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {!isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Evento" component={Event} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Local" component={Local} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
            options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarVisible: false }}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Evento" component={Event} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Local" component={Local} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Perfil" component={Profile} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export const TabNavigator = () => {
  const globalContext = useContext(Context);
  const { isLoggedIn } = globalContext;

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarStyle: {
          position: "absolute",
          paddingBottom: 0,
          backgroundColor: "#121214",
          borderTopWidth: 0,
          paddingBottom: 30,
          paddingTop: 10,
          elevation: 0,
          height: 90,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Início"
        component={StackNavigator}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => {
            if (focused) {
              return <Foundation name="home" size={35} color="#8E05C2" />;
            }
            return <Foundation name="home" size={30} color="#8D8D99" />;
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Ingressos"
        component={ticket}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => {
            if (focused) {
              return <FontAwesome name="ticket" size={33} color="#8E05C2" />;
            }
            return <FontAwesome name="ticket" size={28} color="#8D8D99" />;
          },
        }}
      />
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Perfil"
          component={Profile}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => {
              if (focused) {
                return <FontAwesome5 name="user-alt" size={28} color="#8E05C2" />;
              }
              return <FontAwesome5 name="user-alt" size={23} color="#8D8D99" />;
            },
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size, focused }) => {
              if (focused) {
                return <FontAwesome5 name="user-alt-slash" size={28} color="#8E05C2" />;
              }
              return <FontAwesome5 name="user-alt-slash" size={23} color="#8D8D99" />;
            },
          }}
        />
      )}
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the Login screen outside of the tab navigator. That way it will render on top of the tab navigator when you navigate to it.

You need to make a new stack navigator that will have your TabNavigator and Login components as screens. You can also add modals and dialogs if they are fullscreen in this MainStack, and they will show above the tabbar

```
//New stack navigator
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();
export const MainStackNavigator = () => {
  const globalContext = useContext(Context);
  const { isLoggedIn } = globalContext;

  return (
    <MainStack.Navigator>
          <MainStack.Screen
            name="TabNavigator"
            component={TabNavigator}
          />
      {!isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          <MainStack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
            options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarVisible: false }}
          />
        </>
      ) : null
      }
    </MainStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```